Exercise 2-2(c) from Do Carmo's Differential Forms and Applications

Let $\omega$ be a 1-form defined on $U=\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ such that the following relations hold: $d\omega=0$ and $$\lim_{x^2+y^2\to 0}\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cdot\omega\right)=0$$ then $\omega$ is exact on $U$.

So I have solved the previous parts of the exercise in which I used the fact that $\omega$ was given bounded in a disk and using an inequality of the line integral of $\omega$, I showed that all line integrals must be $0$, hence $\omega$ would be exact. Now, from this limit I cannot deduce that $\omega$ is bounded, as various counterexamples exist, and so I cannot use the previous parts to prove the exactness here. Surely $\omega$ must be locally exact from the Poincaré lemma but I don't see how I can use this limit to deduce global exactness. Any help?

You can still use that limit hypothesis to show that line integrals around circles of radius $r$ are going to $0$ as $r\to 0$.

I have reached this far: Let $c:[0,2\pi]\longrightarrow\partial B(0,r),\ c(t)=r(cost,sint)$ be the parameterization of the circle of radius $r$ and then using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and the fact that the circle is compact, we have that:
\begin{align*}
\left\lvert \int_c\omega\right\rvert&=\left\lvert\int_0^{2\pi}\omega(c(t))\cdot c'(t)dt\right\rvert\newline
&\le r\int_0^{2\pi}\lvert\omega(c(t))\rvert dt\newline
&\le 2\pi r\cdot\underset{t\in [a,b]}{max}\lvert\omega(c(t))\rvert
\end{align*}

How do I use the given limit here? Also, suppose that this is true and that the line integrals over every circle are $0$, then I would also need to show that every closed curve is homotopic to a circle (probably dependent on the winding number) for the form to be exact, right? (since we need the integral to vanish for every closed curve). I have found a homotopy between simple closed curves and the unit circle, but I can't see how to show it for a random closed curve.

First of all, you should be evaluating $\omega(c(t))$ on $c'(t)$, not dotting, but I know what you mean; you then need to interpret $|\omega|$ appropriately. But the given limit tells you that $r\max_{|x|=r}|\omega(x)| \to 0$. Next, you use Stokes's Theorem to show that the integral over a large circle must then be $0$. You don't need arbitrary curves. To show $\omega$ is exact, all you need is path-independence on rectangular paths, say. But you can make an argument that any path is homotopic to a multiple of the unit circle if you insist. I just don't encourage beating that to death.
